# Component List don't update state after deleting one item

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, state

I have an issue trying to update a list of stateful  components created with by mapping a list of strings. The issue is showing when i remove one of this components by slicing the array to remove an element by its index.

Every component has his own state, that im fetching from an API. the problems is that when i remove an element of the array, the state of next component overlaps the one that i deleted Component.

My code looks something similar to this:

```
class MyDashboard extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    activeItems: [0,1,2,3],
  }
 this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
}

removeItem(indx){
 let tempItems= this.state.activeItems;
 tempItems.splice(indx,1);
 this.setState({activeItems:tempItems});
}

render(){
    let conditionalDash;
    let conditionalComponent;
    let temporalArray = this.state.activeEntries.map((entry , i) => {
      return  (<MyDash key={i} index {i}/> removeItem={this.removeItem});
});

render(){
 return (
   <div id='dashContainer'>
    {temporalArray}
   </div>
  )
 } 
}
```

In my MyDashComponent i have a something like this:

```
class MyDash extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
   fetchedData:null,
  }
 }
componentDidMount(){
  API.fetchData(this.props.index).then(response => {
    this.setState({fetchData:response.data})
  )
}
render(){
 return(
  <div> {this.props.index} {this.state.fetchedData}</div>
 )
}
}
```

Is there something that i'm missing?

The behavior that i'm getting is that when the i remove the this.state.activeItems[2] the state of this element is the same as the previous component. I was expecting that the state of the element[2] will be the same state that has the element[3].

Edit:
Something that i forget to tell,  is that the props of MyDash component are correct, is just the state that doesnt belong to the component, it is from the deleted component.

Thanks for reading and i hope that somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the bug it was that the key of the list that i was using, it was the index of the map method, i read that it has to be a unique key. Luckily this fixed the render action and the state doesnt overlap anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Who have mixed the behaviour or `slice` and `splice`

`slice` returns you a new array whereas `splice` modifies the existing one

According to MDN docs:

> `splice:` The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by
>   removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.
>
> Syntax:   array.splice(start, deleteCount)
>
> `slice:` The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an
>   array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not
>   included). The original array will not be modified.
>
> syntax:
>
> ```
> arr.slice()
>  arr.slice(begin)
>  arr.slice(begin, end)
> ```

You might change your code to

```
removeItem(indx){
   let tempItems= this.state.activeItems;
   tempItems.splice(indx,1);
   this.setState({ activeItems:tempItems });
}
```

Also you shouldn't mutate the state directly, you should create a copy of the state array and then update it.

```
removeItem(indx){
   let tempItems= [...this.state.activeItems]; // this is do a shallow copy, you could use something else depending on your usecase
   tempItems.splice(indx,1);
   this.setState({ activeItems:tempItems });
}
```

Comment: My bad, i am using the splice method, i fixed the typo. Whats the difference of creating the tempItems like you did it with a spread operator, than creating it as a copy like i did it?  I will try your answer, thanks

Comment: In your case you are assigning the reference of state array to tempItems and then then modifiying tempItems, modifies state array as well, however, it doesn't have an impact as you setState again. But you should clone your state array and then modify it as a pattern

Comment: That makes sense,  thanks for the explanation i will try it asap 

Comment: All that I need was `tempArray = [...array];` instead of `tempArray = array;`. And also,  I think you just gave me the reason why the original array in my Flutter project was changing. I searched for it but found nothing, even declaring `const` array was of no help. Thanks for helping in two things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the item:

```
removeItem(idx) {
  this.setState({
    activeItems: this.state.activeItems.filter((_, index) => index !== idx)
  });
}
```

or

```
removeItem(idx) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    activeItems: prevState.activeItems.filter((_, index) => index !== idx)
  }));
}
```